# How to fix this error "The non-nullable variable '_mediaQueryData' must be initialized. "

Tags: android, flutter, dart

When I created my size config file I encountered this error. I am new to flutter and I was trying to build an E-commerce App. Even though I searched online I didn't find any solution to this problem.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SizeConfig {
  static MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
  static double screenWidth;
  static double screenHeight;
  static double defaultSize;
  static Orientation orientation;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
    orientation = _mediaQueryData.orientation;
  }
}

// Get the proportionate height as per screen size
double getProportionateScreenHeight(double inputHeight) {
  double screenHeight = SizeConfig.screenHeight;
  // 812 is the layout height that designer use
  return (inputHeight / 812.0) * screenHeight;
}

// Get the proportionate height as per screen size
double getProportionateScreenWidth(double inputWidth) {
  double screenWidth = SizeConfig.screenWidth;
  // 375 is the layout width that designer use
  return (inputWidth / 375.0) * screenWidth;
}
```

Comment: Your init() function is an instance method - Use a constructor to initialize your fields instead: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors

Comment: It says it _mediaQueryData can't be accessed through an instance.  When I declared it as "static late"  the code worked. I don't know whether the same would error occur as I move forward. Thank you for your answer Michael.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've been probably following tutorials from the past year where this was possible, but for now, you have to add "?" at the currently empty variables as "double screenWidth".

In Dart, all variables are non-nullable by default. We cannot assign a null value to a variable because it’ll throw a compilation error, that's why we use the "?" sign.

Also - Appending ! to any variable tells the compiler that the variable is not null, and can be used safely.

The solution you're looking for would probably go something like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SizeConfig {
  static MediaQueryData? _mediaQueryData;
  static double? screenWidth;
  static double? screenHeight;
  static double? defaultSize;
  static Orientation? orientation;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData!.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData!.size.height;
    orientation = _mediaQueryData!.orientation;

    defaultSize = orientation == Orientation.landscape
        ? screenHeight! * 0.024
        : screenWidth! * 0.024;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Nesko. This code cleared the errors i faced earlier but now when I call the SizeConfig().init(context) function I get No MediaQuery Widget Ancestor error. Do u know how to fix that?